# Magento plug in php alteration

Tags: php, ce-1.9.0.1, plugin

I think this is an incredibly simple question (but I maybe wrong) so I apologise if it is.

We have a module with this code in it

```
public function getCustomerGroup()
{
    $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
    return Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId)->getCode();
}
```

Instead of its current value, I would like it just to return another value (I shall call this value 'value') for everything / everyone, what do I need to replace the

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
    return Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId)->getCode();
```

To get this value to show?

Comment: as far i understand it just replace 

    `return Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId)->getCode();`

with 

    `return 'your desired value';`

Comment: Thankyou for the swift reply that has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just replace return

`Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId)->getCode()`;

with

```
return 'your desired value';
```